# Python will not change a boolean value after it runs through a function

Tags: python, function, boolean

```
from random import randrange

on = ''

max_number = 0
random_number = 0

def start():
    max_number = int(input('Enter max generated number: '))
    random_number = randrange(max_number)
    print(random_number)
    on = True

start()

print(on) # returns false??
```

for a school project, i need to make a number guessing game. This is the start code i have. I declared "on" before the start function but the function wont change the value of the boolean to true

Comment: on = False. I was trying new methods and copied the wrong one. it should not be on = ' '

Comment: Using global values is a bad habit to get into; it will end up slowing you down later when you have to unlearn it (and you *will* have to unlearn it).  Use `return` to return the values from the function to the caller, and have the caller assign them.  I.e. end your function with `return max_number, random_number` and then call it like `max_number, random_number = start()`.  I doubt that you need the `on` variable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, `on` is a "local" variable, only seen and used inside the scope of the function. To change the value of any variable inside and outside the function, you need to type the command `global {variable}`, usually at the top of a function. In your case, add this to your function:

```
def start():
    global on <-- Right Here
    max_number = int(input('Enter max generated number: '))
```

You can research more about `global` and `nonlocal` variables online.
Acknowledging @Samwise comment, global and nonlocal variables aren't always the best option, but I think that it's best to learn it anyway (the more you know!). He is correct, that you will likely not even need the `on` variable, and also that using a `return` statement is the best option.